# Cannot parse ttf glyf table

Tags: java, parsing, truetype

my task is to parse a ttf file to get the glyph outline information. I wrote the following code to read the glyf table and I just can't figure out what's wrong with it. Theoretically, this should be right. The only thing that's kinda strange is that every line I used to extract a single bit from the flags had different results, maybe I'm just not reading the right bytes from the flag, but I tried so many of them that by the time I should have really picked the correct one. Is the Microsoft doc still up to date or did the glyf table change in a way? In case someone wonders what the error are I'm getting: it's actually a couple of different ones:

first of all, I get an array out of bounds exceptions if I don't insert a line that checks whether or not the current position in the array is 0 and the flag for "copy the last coordinate" is set when I parse the coordinates, which would mean, that the current x / y coordinate should be the same as the last one, even though this is the first coordinate in the array.

if I check if it's the first one in the array or not and just set the value to 0 if it is, and draw all the points to the screen there is absolutely no order or pattern in any of them.

the last problem is, that there seems to be a problem with the array size, since some of them are so long that they also read parts of other arrays and others are too short and don't read the entire glyf data

this is my code:

```
private static class GlyfTable {
        public Glyf[] glyfs;


        public GlyfTable(ByteFile file, TableDirectory directory, LocaTable loca, MaxpTable maxp) {
            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("glyf").offset);
            glyfs = new Glyf[maxp.numGlyphs];
            for(int i = 0; i < maxp.numGlyphs; i++) {
                file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("glyf").offset + loca.offsets[i]);
              
                glyfs[i] = new Glyf();
                glyfs[i].numberOfContours = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].xMin = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].yMin = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].xMax = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].yMax = file.getInt16();
                if(glyfs[i].numberOfContours >= 0) {
                    glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours = new int[glyfs[i].numberOfContours];
                    for(int g = 0; g < glyfs[i].numberOfContours; g++) {
                        glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours[g] = file.getUint16();
                    }
                    glyfs[i].instructionLength = file.getUint16();
                    glyfs[i].instructions = new int[glyfs[i].instructionLength];
                    for(int c = 0; c < glyfs[i].instructionLength; c++) {
                        glyfs[i].instructions[c] = file.getUint8();
                    }

                    int pointCount = glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours[glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours.length - 1] + 1;
                    glyfs[i].flags = new byte[pointCount];
                    for(int f = 0; f < pointCount; f++) {
                        byte flag = file.getByte();
                        glyfs[i].flags[f] = flag;
                        if((flag & (1 << 3)) != 0) {
                            int repeat = file.getUint8();
                            for(int r = 0; r < repeat; r++) {
                                f++;
                                glyfs[i].flags[f] = flag;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    glyfs[i].xCoordinates = new int[pointCount];
                    for(int c = 0; c < pointCount; c++) {
                        if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 1)) != 0) {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 4)) != 0) {
                                glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8();
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8() * -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 4)) != 0) {
                                if(c > 0) {
                                    glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c - 1];
                                }
                                else {
                                    glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = file.getInt16();
                            }
                        }
                    }



                    glyfs[i].yCoordinates = new int[pointCount];

                    for(int c = 0; c < pointCount; c++) {
                        if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 2)) != 0) {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 5)) != 0) {
                                glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8();
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8() * -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 5)) != 0) {
                                if(c == 0) {
                                    glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = 0;
                                }
                                else {
                                    glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c - 1];
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = file.getInt16();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static class Glyf {
            public int numberOfContours;
            public int xMin;
            public int yMin;
            public int xMax;
            public int yMax;

            public int[] endPtsOfContours;
            int instructionLength;
            int[] instructions;
            byte[] flags;
            int[] xCoordinates;
            int[] yCoordinates;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: this is the entire code of the class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class Font_MK2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TTFFile ttf = new TTFFile("path to font");
}

private static class TTFFile {
    ByteFile file;

    private TableDirectory directory;
    private CmapTable cmap;
    private MaxpTable maxp;
    private LocaTable loca;
    private HeadTable head;
    private GlyfTable glyf;

    public TTFFile(String path) throws IOException {
        file = new ByteFile(path);
        directory = new TableDirectory(file);
        cmap = new CmapTable(file,directory);
        maxp = new MaxpTable(file,directory);
        head = new HeadTable(file,directory);
        loca = new LocaTable(file, directory, maxp, head);
        glyf = new GlyfTable(file, directory, loca, maxp);

    }

    private static class TableDirectory {
        public long sfntVersion;
        public int numTables;
        public int searchRange;
        public int entrySelector;
        public int rangeShift;

        public LinkedHashMap<String,TableRecord> tableRecords;

        public TableDirectory(ByteFile file) {
            sfntVersion = file.getUint32();
            numTables = file.getUint16();
            searchRange = file.getUint16();
            entrySelector = file.getUint16();
            rangeShift = file.getUint16();

            tableRecords = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < numTables; i++) {
                String tag = file.getTag();
                tableRecords.put(tag,new TableRecord(tag,
                        file.getUint32(),
                        file.getOffset32(),
                        file.getUint32()));
            }
        }

        private static class TableRecord {
            public TableRecord(String tag, long check, long off, long len) {
                tableTag = tag;checksum = check; offset = off; length = len;
            }
            public String tableTag;
            public long checksum;
            public long offset;
            public long length;
        }
    }
    private static class CmapTable {
        public int version;
        public int numTables;
        public encodingRecord[] encodingRecords;
        public int[] CharacterCodes;

        public CmapTable(ByteFile file, TableDirectory directory) {
            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("cmap").offset);
            version = file.getUint16();
            numTables = file.getUint16();
            encodingRecords = new encodingRecord[numTables];

            long OffsetToUse = 0;
            long encodingToUse = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < numTables; i++) {
                encodingRecords[i] = new encodingRecord(file.getUint16(), file.getUint16(), file.getOffset32());
                if(encodingRecords[i].platformID == 0 && encodingRecords[i].encodingID == 3) {
                    OffsetToUse = encodingRecords[i].subtableOffset;
                    encodingToUse = encodingRecords[i].encodingID;
                }
            }

            if(encodingToUse != 3) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Encoding not recognized");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("head").offset + OffsetToUse);
            if(file.getUint16() == 0) {
                int subtableLength = file.getUint16();
                int language = file.getUint16();
                CharacterCodes = new int[subtableLength];
                for(int i = 0; i < subtableLength; i++) {
                    CharacterCodes[i] = file.getUint8();
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Format not recognized");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        static class encodingRecord {
            public int platformID;
            public int encodingID;
            public long subtableOffset;

            public encodingRecord(int platformID, int encodingID, long subtableOffset) {
                this.platformID = platformID; this.encodingID = encodingID; this.subtableOffset = subtableOffset;
            }
        }
    }
    private static class MaxpTable{
        public int version;
        public int numGlyphs;
        public int maxPoints;
        public int maxContours;
        public int maxCompositePoints;
        public int maxCompositeContours;
        public int maxZones;
        public int maxTwilightPoints;
        public int maxStorage;
        public int maxFunctionDefs;
        public int maxInstructionDefs;
        public int maxStackElements;
        public int maxSizeOfInstructions;
        public int maxComponentElements;
        public int maxComponentDepth;

        public MaxpTable(ByteFile file, TableDirectory directory) {
            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("maxp").offset);
            version = file.getVersion()[0];
            if(version == 1) {
                numGlyphs = file.getUint16();
                maxPoints = file.getUint16();
                maxContours = file.getUint16();
                maxCompositePoints = file.getUint16();
                maxCompositeContours = file.getUint16();
                maxZones = file.getUint16();
                maxTwilightPoints = file.getUint16();
                maxStorage = file.getUint16();
                maxFunctionDefs = file.getUint16();
                maxInstructionDefs = file.getUint16();
                maxStackElements = file.getUint16();
                maxSizeOfInstructions = file.getUint16();
                maxComponentElements = file.getUint16();
                maxComponentDepth = file.getUint16();
            }
            else {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("unknown Version");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static class HeadTable {
        public int majorVersion;
        public int minorVersion;
        public float fontRevision;
        public long checksumAdjustment;
        public long magicNumber;
        public int flags;
        public int unitsPerEm;
        public long created;
        public long modified;
        public int xMin;
        public int yMin;
        public int xMax;
        public int yMax;
        public int macStyle;
        public int lowestRecPPEM;
        public int fontDirectionHint;
        public int indexToLocFormat;
        public int glyphDataFormat;
        public HeadTable(ByteFile file, TableDirectory directory) {
            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("head").offset);
            majorVersion = file.getUint16();
            minorVersion = file.getUint16();
            fontRevision = file.getFixed();
            checksumAdjustment = file.getUint32();
            magicNumber = file.getUint32();
            flags = file.getUint16();
            unitsPerEm = file.getUint16();
            created = file.getDate();
            modified = file.getDate();
            xMin = file.getInt16();
            yMin = file.getInt16();
            xMax = file.getInt16();
            yMax = file.getInt16();
            macStyle = file.getUint16();
            lowestRecPPEM = file.getUint16();
            fontDirectionHint = file.getInt16();
            indexToLocFormat = file.getInt16();
            glyphDataFormat = file.getInt16();
        }
    }
    private static class LocaTable {
        long[] offsets;
        public LocaTable(ByteFile file, TableDirectory directory, MaxpTable maxp, HeadTable head) {
            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("loca").offset);
            offsets = new long[maxp.numGlyphs + 1];
            if(head.indexToLocFormat == 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < maxp.numGlyphs + 1; i++) {
                    offsets[i] = file.getOffset16() * 2l;
                }
            }
            else if(head.indexToLocFormat == 1) {
                for(int i = 0; i < maxp.numGlyphs + 1; i++) {
                    offsets[i] = file.getOffset32();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static class GlyfTable {
        public Glyf[] glyfs;


        public GlyfTable(ByteFile file, TableDirectory directory, LocaTable loca, MaxpTable maxp) {
            file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("glyf").offset);
            glyfs = new Glyf[maxp.numGlyphs];
            for(int i = 0; i < maxp.numGlyphs; i++) {
                file.setPosition(directory.tableRecords.get("glyf").offset + loca.offsets[i]);
           
                glyfs[i] = new Glyf();
                glyfs[i].numberOfContours = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].xMin = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].yMin = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].xMax = file.getInt16();
                glyfs[i].yMax = file.getInt16();
                if(glyfs[i].numberOfContours >= 0) {

                    glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours = new int[glyfs[i].numberOfContours];
                    for(int g = 0; g < glyfs[i].numberOfContours; g++) {
                        glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours[g] = file.getUint16();
                    }
                    glyfs[i].instructionLength = file.getUint16();
                    glyfs[i].instructions = new int[glyfs[i].instructionLength];
                    for(int c = 0; c < glyfs[i].instructionLength; c++) {
                        glyfs[i].instructions[c] = file.getUint8();
                    }

                    int pointCount = glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours[glyfs[i].endPtsOfContours.length - 1] + 1;
                    glyfs[i].flags = new byte[pointCount];
                    for(int f = 0; f < pointCount; f++) {
                        byte flag = file.getByte();
                        glyfs[i].flags[f] = flag;
                        if((flag & (1 << 3)) != 0) {
                            int repeat = file.getUint8();
                            for(int r = 0; r < repeat; r++) {
                                f++;
                                glyfs[i].flags[f] = flag;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    glyfs[i].xCoordinates = new int[pointCount];
                    for(int c = 0; c < pointCount; c++) {
                        if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 1)) != 0) {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 4)) != 0) {
                                glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8();
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8() * -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 4)) != 0) {
                                if(c > 0) {
                                    glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c - 1];
                                }
                                else {
                                    glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].xCoordinates[c] = file.getInt16();
                            }
                        }
                    }



                    glyfs[i].yCoordinates = new int[pointCount];

                    for(int c = 0; c < pointCount; c++) {
                        if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 2)) != 0) {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 5)) != 0) {
                                glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8();
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = file.getUint8() * -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if((glyfs[i].flags[c] & (1 << 5)) != 0) {
                                if(c == 0) {
                                    glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = 0;
                                }
                                else {
                                    glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c - 1];
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                glyfs[i].yCoordinates[c] = file.getInt16();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public String toBitString(final byte val) {
            return String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(val & 0xFF))
                    .replace(' ', '0');
        }
        static class Glyf {
            public int numberOfContours;
            public int xMin;
            public int yMin;
            public int xMax;
            public int yMax;

            public int[] endPtsOfContours;
            int instructionLength;
            int[] instructions;
            byte[] flags;
            int[] xCoordinates;
            int[] yCoordinates;
        }
    }
}
private static class ByteFile {
    private byte[] file;
    private long position;
    public ByteFile(String path) throws IOException {
        file = Files.readAllBytes(new File(path).toPath());
    }
    byte getByte() {
        return file[(int)position++];
    }
    public int getUint8() {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {0,0,0,getByte()};
        long l = 0;
        l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
        return (int)l;
    }
    public int getInt8() {
        return getByte();
    }
    public boolean[] getBit8() {
        String s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(getByte() & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        return new boolean[] {s1.charAt(0) == '1',s1.charAt(1) == '1',s1.charAt(2) == '1',s1.charAt(3) == '1',s1.charAt(4) == '1',s1.charAt(5) == '1',s1.charAt(6) == '1',s1.charAt(7) == '1'};
    }
    public int getUint16() {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {0,0,getByte(),getByte()};
        long l = 0;
        l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
        return (int)l;
    }
    public int getInt16() {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {0,0,getByte(),getByte()};
        long l = 0;
        l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
        return l;
    }
    public long getUint24() {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {0,getByte(),getByte(),getByte()};
        long l = 0;
        l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
        return (int)l;
    }
    public long getUint32() {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {getByte(),getByte(),getByte(),getByte()};
        long l = 0;
        l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
        return l;
    }
    public int getInt32() {
        return (getByte() << 24) | (getByte() << 16) | (getByte() << 8) | getByte();
    }
    public float getFixed() {
        int s = getInt32();
        return Float.parseFloat((s << 16) + "." + ((0 << 16)));
    }
    public int getFword() {
        return getInt16();
    }
    public int getUFWord() {
        return getUint16();
    }
    public float getF2DOT14() {
        int r = getInt16();
        return Float.parseFloat((0 << 14 | r) + "." + (r << 14) + "f");
    }
    public long getDate() {
        return (getUint32() << 32) | getUint32();
    }
    public String getTag() {
        return new String(new char[] {(char)getByte(), (char)getByte(), (char)getByte(), (char)getByte()});
    }
    public int getOffset16() {
        return getUint16();
    }
    public long getOffset32() {
        return getUint32();
    }
    public int[] getVersion() {
        return new int[] {getInt16(), getInt16()};
    }
    public long getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(long Position) {
        position = Position;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check that `directory.tableRecords.get("glyf").offset` has the correct value? And also the location offsets? You don't show the code which reads these indexes; if they are not read/computed correctly, nothing is going to work.

Comment: The entire class is attached now, but the only thing that I could think of as being wrong aswell is the ByteFile class, since I don't have much experience with byteshift operators.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). On the other hand, this isn't really a small program. I think it might be worth adding a guideline **How to debug larger programs?**: Start debugging before the program gets so big. :-)

Comment: Why are you using int[] for instructions instead of byte[]? (I see you're reading using GetUint8, so that's good.)

Comment: This is the current glyf table spec: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf

Comment: The reason I used int is just that I used it for everything except for the flaggs. I Fixed it now, the error was somewhere in the ByteFile class, which I rewrote and now it's sort of working.